# android mysql to sqlite conversion

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I am converting mysql database to sqlite 3 database using the script provided here:
http://www.jbip.net/content/how-convert-mysql-sqlite

But when i execute this script, I get following error:

mysql-sqllite.sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable

Is there anything that I can do here?

Regards,
Sapan

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be not a specific problem with the script, but with your box. Teh googles told me among others this sollution:

http://www.linux.org.za/Lists-Archives/glug-0008/msg00693.html

It says:

> Check the file :
>   /usr/src/linux/include/linux/tasks.h
>
> Change

```
 #define NR_TASKS        512     /* On x86 Max 4092, or 4090 w/APM configured. */
```

> to whatvever you want..

It seems that you can't run fork (kindof like: start a new task), because you're not allowed (resource is not available). So one of the processes can't be started.